# Mock class using Weld without JBoss instance running

Tags: java, junit, ejb, weld

I have a problem with mocking class using Weld and JUnit 5. I've tried already different approaches, but none of them turned out to be satisfying. I would like to mock a few EJB classes without JBoss instance running in order to use it in tests.

I've tried something like this similar to the tutorial I found but I cannot mock multiple classes using this approach.

```
@WeldSetup
public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from(RunService.class).addBeans(createBeans()).build();

  static Bean<?> createBeans() {
    return MockBean.builder()
            .types(RunService.class)
            .scope(ApplicationScoped.class)
            .creating(
                    when(mock(RunService.class).findSchedulerUserId()).thenReturn(10).getMock())
            .build();
            }
```

[Source I've found but only with one mocked class, but I would like to have multiple](https://dzone.com/articles/weld-junit-easy-testing-of-cdi-beans)

I've tried to create a List and pass it as argument in addBeans() method in WeldInitiator but then I get a following error from Mockito:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
-> at com.gft.prevista.nap.filescanner.scan.FileDispatchTest.createBeans(FileDispatchTest.java:36)
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
   when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
   doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
   verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

I'd be very grateful if you have any hints that could lead me in the right direction.

EDIT: I've found something like this yet maybe this would be helpful to find a solution to that:

https://github.com/weld/weld-junit/blob/master/junit4/src/test/java/org/jboss/weld/junit4/bean/AddBeanTest.java

Comment: Does the error still occur if you create the mocked RunService as a separate statement instead of inline inside the `when` call?

Comment: @JonK unfortunately yes :(

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem, the `addBeans()` method allows you to specify multiple bean, or it can be invoked repeatedly as shows in `AddBeanTest` that you found. What's insufficient about that? Also have you noted the capability of `WeldInitiator` to mock EJB factory with `setEjbFactory` method? Look [here](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit/blob/master/junit-common/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/junit/AbstractWeldInitiator.java#L445)